# React-Native-Router-Flux Actions Refresh Tabs and keep sub-scene navigation stack

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-router-flux

here is my problem, 
I have this configuration using [react-native-router-flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/API_CONFIGURATION.md) 3.39.1 and RN 0.40.0:

```
<Router >
  <Scene key='bottomBar' tabs hideNavBar tabBarStyle={Styles.tabBar}>
    <Scene
    key='Tab-A'
    title='Tab A'
    icon={TabIcon}
    onPress={() => { Actions.refresh({ key: 'Scene-A' }) }}
    style={Styles.main}>
        <Scene key='Scene-A' component={SceneA} style={Styles.main} />
        <Scene key='Scene-A-1' title='Scene A 1' component={SceneA1}/>
        <Scene key='Scene-A-2' title='Scene A 2' component={SceneA2}/>
    </Scene>
    <Scene
    key='Tab-B'
    title='Tab B'
    icon={TabIcon}
    onPress={() => { Actions.refresh({ key: 'Scene-B' }) }}
    style={Styles.main}>
        <Scene key='Scene-B' component={SceneA} style={Styles.main} />
    </Scene>
  </Scene>
</Router>
```

The problem is : 
 
When, from **Scene-A** I popTo **Scene-A-1** then go to **Scene-B** Tab, if I click back on **Tab-A**, the Router present **Scene-A** instead of **Scene-A-1**.

In fact my new navigation stack is : 
-- Tab A 
|__ Scene-A 
|__ Scene-A-1 
|__ Scene-A

Instead of : 
-- Tab A 
|__ Scene-A 
|__ Scene-A-1

I saw that [this pull request](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/pull/1312) may fix it but it doesn't works in my side.

How can I do to refresh the scene with the last navigation stack ?
Do I have to use different kind of ActionConst ?

Thank you